# How to make full system backup in windows server 2003?

Tags: windows-server-2003, backup

I´d like to know how to full backup windows server 2003 system. I was told that 2003 backup tool cannot make such a thing as opposed to windows server 2008.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Backup wizard in Windows Server 2003 to make a full system backup and a recovery disk that you can use to restore the server. It's called ASR (Automated System Recovery).

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779908(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Thanks, but it does not backup any data, isnt it? Only system files and windows configuration, i think

Comment: Hi. The server has no floppy, so is there any way to backup to external or network drive without needing recovery disk? Or maybe can i use usb pendrive instead if floppy?